# Easy To Note/Write/Type/Outline/See

Tags: text-editor

I need a text editor meeting some specific requirements:

**minimal requirements**

- can make bullet points easy like if you type '* [space]' then it would make a bullet point
- what I type into the software is responsive to the size of the window (going to keep the window/app like a 'sidebar')
- is easy to hide/expand all info under a higher-level bullet point
- can bold (auto-bold the first line/bullet point is a plus)
- minimal UI (prefer completely clean UI)

Site, app, anything, only the above matters unless I forgot something, or something works differently than assumed. File format is irrelevant, any OS or web-app will do. No price considerations currently.

Comment: ok.... i guess nobody takes notes...

Comment: I wouldn't say that. But maybe very few have your specific requirements.

Comment: yea you're right, most ppl don't do much, there's tons and a whole category that fits what im looking for, but most don't do much so have little needs